# How to show please wait while ajax request process in complete

Tags: ajax

this code is working fine, all that i want is to make ajax say please wait while still requesting for information: here is this code.

```
function products(){  

   if (document.getElementById('date').value.length == 0) {
     alert("Please Pick Date");
     document.getElementById('date').focus();
     return false;
   }

   var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('sum');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var usr = document.getElementById('usr').value;
    var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    var queryString = "?usr=" + usr + "&date=" + date;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax_prom.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 

}
```

Comment: Show message, animated icon, whatever, before `ajaxRequest.send(null);` and hide it at `if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){`  You can get a huge number of animated gifs at http://www.ajaxload.info/ and http://preloaders.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
In your page, add a div with the id - divAjaxRequestInProgress. Add the text you want to show while the ajax request is in progress to this div. You could have an animated gif as well. Now, show this when you start your ajax processing and hide it once the request is complete. 


function products(){  

   if (document.getElementById('date').value.length == 0) {
     alert("Please Pick Date");
     document.getElementById('date').focus();
     return false;
   }

   $("#divAjaxRequestInProgress").show();

   var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('sum');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
        $("#divAjaxRequestInProgress").hide();
    }
    var usr = document.getElementById('usr').value;
    var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    var queryString = "?usr=" + usr + "&date=" + date;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax_prom.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 

}
```

I have just added 2 lines to your code - one to show and one to hide the div.

Comment: ArunGeorge I so appreciate your time out to respond productively to my question. please I have a little challenge with it. see below the div i created 

<div id="divAjaxRequestInProgress">Loading</div>

but it shows Loading before the process even start

please is there a way i could have done it.